# Can i change the height of a uitableview's tableHeaderView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to change the tableView.tableHeaderView frame so i can make it bigger but with no effect. Is tableView.tableHeaderView's frame fixed or is it adjustable?

Answer (score -18, accepted):

Write this into your UITableViewDelegate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: This solution is for a section header view-- not a tableHeaderView

Answer (score 18):

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
tableView.tableHeaderView = your_headerView;
```

See also: [Resizing a UITableView's tableHeaderView](http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/resizing-a-uitableviews-tableheaderview/)

Comment: I think because UITableView recalculate tableHeaderView height during rotation or set.

Answer (score 0):

It is flexible, If you have tried following code and its still not working,
then Try changing Header View size in Interface builder.

Create a UIView with the things you want for your Header and add view

```
UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, heightYouWant)];
tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[yourTableView setTableHeaderView:tempView];
//[yourTableView setTableFooterView:tempView]; you can also use Footer in same way
[emptyView release];
```

you can add other controls in the tempView to create it run time.